# Is it possible to determine which rows are affected by SQL Server UPDATE?

Tags: java, sql, sql-server

I am using a Java program to update a SQL Server 2017 database. Currently, while testing my `UPDATE` statements, I am not committing the changes (`connection.setAutoCommit(false)`).

When I print out the number of rows affected, the count is much lower than expected (the UPDATE statements should be updating every row).

Here is some sample code that demonstrates the loop I am using to issue the `UPDATE` statements:

```
    // List of users that need to be updated
    List<User> updatedUsers = new ArrayList<>();

    // Connect to database
    Connection connection = null;
    connection = DataFiles.getServerConnection();
    connection.setAutoCommit(false);

    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;

    int rowsAffected = 0;
    final int batchSize = 1000;
    int count = 0;

    // Create an UPDATE statement for each record to be updated
    for (User user : updatedUsers) {

        StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder(
                "UPDATE USERS SET\n"
        );

        sql.append("USER_TYPE=?,\n")
                .append("FIRST_NAME=?,\n")
                .append("LAST_NAME=?,\n")
                .append("EMAIL_ADDRESS=?\n");
        sql.append("WHERE USER_ID=?");

        // Fill each ?
        preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql.toString());

        preparedStatement.setString(1, user.getUserTypeId());
        preparedStatement.setString(2, user.getFirstName());
        preparedStatement.setString(3, user.getLastName());
        preparedStatement.setString(4, user.getEmailAddress());
        preparedStatement.setString(5, user.getUserId());
        preparedStatement.addBatch();

        // Submit in batches of 1000
        if (++count % batchSize == 0) {
            rowsAffected += IntStream.of(preparedStatement.executeBatch()).sum();
            preparedStatement.clearBatch();
        }
    }
    System.out.println(count);

    rowsAffected += IntStream.of(preparedStatement.executeBatch()).sum();
    preparedStatement.clearBatch();
    preparedStatement.close();

    System.out.println(rowsAffected + " rows affected!");
```

---

My `WHERE` statement should be matching a record for every pass of the loop, yet I am getting `33 rows affected` instead of the 32,000 I am expecting.

Is there a way to return the rows affected? I want to compare the matches to those that did not match.

*I have already tried adapting my loop to a `SELECT` statement with the same `WHERE` criteria and that returns all 32,000 records, so I'm confident that the records DO exist.*

Comment: @Nick - It is possible, but not likely. I do not expect all 32,000 to be updated, actually, but a lot more than 33. But that is why I would like to know which rows were affected, so I can find out why.

Comment: This is a production database, so I'd like to convince myself it's accurate before I commit the updates.

Comment: Are you aware that you only print `rowsAffected` once, at the very end of your code?  How are you checking the update count after each batch?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - Yes, but I add to `rowsAffected` with each batch update. So my assumption when I print is that is would reflect all rows affected from each batch.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I've learnt something new today.

Comment: @Zephyr Print out the raw query from your Java code, and make sure it is legitimate and what you expect.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - I am not sure how to print out a populated `PreparedStatement`. Is that even possible?

Comment: @Zephyr Just try using `System.out.println(preparedStatement)`.  There is a good chance your driver will support this.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - It does not appear to. The output is just `SQLServerPreparedStatement: n` (showing the number of the statement)

Comment: SQL Server, the gift that keeps on giving :-) ... well you can still step through your code and check the parameters which you are binding.

Comment: Thank you, Tim. I'll try that in the morning if there no one finds a way to get the affected rows by then. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a new PreparedStatement in every iteration of your loop. You need to queue up batch executions on the same preparedStatement object that you call executeBatch. Currently you are only ever executing the 1000th queued query.

```
StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder(
    "UPDATE USERS SET\n"
);

sql.append("USER_TYPE=?,\n")
    .append("FIRST_NAME=?,\n")
    .append("LAST_NAME=?,\n")
   .append("EMAIL_ADDRESS=?\n");
sql.append("WHERE USER_ID=?");

preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql.toString());

for (User user : updatedUsers) {
        preparedStatement.setString(1, user.getUserTypeId());
        preparedStatement.setString(2, user.getFirstName());
        preparedStatement.setString(3, user.getLastName());
        preparedStatement.setString(4, user.getEmailAddress());
        preparedStatement.setString(5, user.getUserId());
        preparedStatement.addBatch();

        // Submit in batches of 1000
        if (++count % batchSize == 0) {
            rowsAffected += IntStream.of(preparedStatement.executeBatch()).sum();
            preparedStatement.clearBatch();
        }
}
```

For determining affected rows (In sql server 2005+) you can use the OUTPUT clause in your SQL to have the database return affected row data. [Article](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/156604/)

Comment: This does solve the issue I was having, so thank you! But it does not actually answer the question of how to retrieve the affected rows.

Comment: Updated my answer.